# Etiquetas númericas en gganimate en el proceso interactivo en un plot de Rstudio

Tags: ggplot2

comunidad.

Tengo un gráfico interactivo en gganimate y ggplot que cambia años tras años los registros de un delito, en este proceso de cambiar de años, el gráfico en movimiento, muestra muchos valores decimales hasta llegar al valor que debe representar el gráfico, siendo que son valores enteros, es decir en mi gráfico si el valor es 1200 en el año 1 y 1300 en el año 2, en esta transición de años mi gráfico muestra las etiquetas 1199.999999 hasta que llega al 1200 y queda estático y de forma iterativa de 1200, a pasar al siguiente año en 1200, retoma muchos decimales (ejemplo 1201.9999) hasta llegar al valor que sigue del año  con el valor de 1300 del año dos, espero haberme explicado.

Sólo es como reducir estas etiqueta, considerando que mis valores de forma estática o cuando llegan a su valor muestra los valores correctos y enteros.

Comment: Hola. Por favor comparte el código con el que haces la animación. Podría estar relacionado con el tipo o variable de transición.

Comment: No sé si ya lo has resuelto, sino sería bueno que agregues el código mínimo con el que realizas la gráfica, sin esto, lo único que podríamos hacer es darte sugerencias varias para que pruebes, lo que habitualmente es la dinámica de los foros, pero en SOes la idea  justamente es evitar ese ida y vuelta, por eso que que se busca que las preguntas sean concretas y que incluyan todos los elementos necesarios para poder comprender y reproducir el problema y eventualmente dar una solución. Saludos.